ASP.NET Core 8 Web API on IIS marked as not secure, in Postman and the browser, when calling it with HTTPS
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that I host on IIS for a client. It was using http for development purposes and everything worked fine but now the client wants to change that to https.
So he issued a certificate pointing to the default domain and added alternate names on a new FQN, created a dns entry in his company's servers to register the new FQN that will be used to call the API. I installed those (installed certificate on the Windows server, created the binding in IIS to use the new FQN as a hostname and ticked the Require Server Name indication, and chose the newly created-installed certificate) and everything works fine functionally wise.
But when I call the API using Postman, I get a little red notice that reads "unable to get local issuer certificate" (SSL verification OFF). So I used the browser to check if the same thing happens and indeed it says the site is not secure. But when I go on the swagger page of the API it says it is secure.
So I used the same certificate with the alternate names on another web app that is deployed there and called it and the browser says that the site is secure. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the certificate and when I open it, it says "Certificate OK".
I've tried rebinding the site and reinstalling the certificate, multiple IIS resets, made sure the API uses https redirection, tried CORS and lots of searching but I can't seem to find an answer to this exact case. My knowledge about certificates and https is limited and I think I am missing something.
How can I get rid of this warning from postman and site not secure in the browser?
EDIT: Images showing the problem https://imgur.com/a/oYfL0MW

"he issued a certificate pointing to the default domain and added alternate names on a new FQN" where did that certificate come from? Public CA or private CA or is it self-signed?

Help yourself by running a report https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

may i know what is your iis hostname and the alternate names you have set in the certificate. could you check both are getting matched or not. is it possible for you to share the error your website is getting, your iis site binding setting and certificate details here. you can hide sensitive information while sharing those details

@JalpaPanchal https://imgur.com/a/oYfL0MW Heres everything I think. I think I covered everything.

After further investigation it seems that when using the browser and not failing to get a page the browser sees the site as secure. But the issue still exists on the API

404 is not an SSL error. You had some kind of SSL issue which you ignored, and now it connected but can't find the page. Check the web server is set up properly.

@Charlieface What do you mean by check the web server is set up properly? I've posted my settings and how it is setup. Also 404 does have something to do with certificate issues. The swagger page, which exists, is working and secure.

No 404 is nothing to do with certificates, it fundamentally means the server is responding but saying it can't find the page you want. You say things like "an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that I host on IIS" but you're note really showing us any of the setup (apart from a few blurred out screenshots).

What part of the setup you want me to show? You haven't asked for any particular info. In the screenshots I show that the bindings are setup and the alternate names are also setup. If you need more info please say so, as these comments are not helpful. Thanks.

Is the swagger page and the issue URL using different domain? have you tried different browsers to test the issue? have you placed the certificate to the trusted root folder as well? Where have you placed the certificate in local machine or current user? From your shared screenshot I noticed that URL where you are facing certificate issue shows not exist? So first make sure that it is accessible with that specific domain and then try to use the https and troubleshoot the certificate issue.
